# javascript/jquery space elimination from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Good day everyone,

I have a text area that takes user input (duh!) and I want to eliminate excess spaces.

#### Example

The string:

> The(s)(s)(s)quick(s)brown(s)(s)fox(s)(s)(s)jumped(s)over(s)the(s)lazy(s)(s)dog!

Should be:

> The(s)quick(s)brown(s)fox(s)jumped(s)over(s)the(s)lazy(s)dog!

(s) = space

I am aware of the `trim()` function in JavaScript to eliminate spaces at both ends (beginning and the end of string), but how do I do that between words and without fully eliminating all spaces? Just stacking them to one space if that makes it easier to understand :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex `(/ +/g, " ")`:

```
var str = "The   quick brown  fox   jumped over the lazy  dog!";
str = str.replace(/ +/g, " "); 
// Results in "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog!"
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p2xR7/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are your friend!

```
str = str.replace(/ +/g, " ");
```